# Seamless configuration for VM with services visible on the host

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have a VM machine (Ubuntu server) running in a host with Ubuntu desktop. I have the following requirements:

- I want the VM to have access to the internet
- I want to run services in the VM, which I need to be reachable from the host
- I do not want to be forced to create NAT rules for each and every service which I will be accessing on the VM
- The host is connected to the network via WLAN: no bridge to WLAN interface is possible.

The solution that I have in mind is:

- one NAT Network adapter to allow the VM to access the internet. This does not allow to access the VM from the internet or from the host (without NAT forwarding rules)
- one Host only adapter, so that I can reach the VM on a specified IP address (usually on the range `192.168.56.101` - `192.168.56.254`, as per-default settings)

Is there an easier setup to satisfy my requirements?

Comment: Did you try it? Any issue with your setup?

Comment: @Biswapriyo indeed. I am not even able to have it running :( https://superuser.com/q/1408396/94612

Comment: As an alternative approach, why not do a single bridged network interface and have the guest's firewall block all incoming except the host's? Or was there an additional reason you needed to have two different IP address ranges?

Comment: @n8te because I have spent over 6 hours trying to setup the bridge interface and it does not work :( . Apparently, bridging to a wlan interface is not obvious. My host is connected to the network via wlan.

Comment: Understood. I fired up virtualbox and tried to reproduce your issue but mine doesn't give me any trouble matching your setup. Not sure where you're going wrong.

Comment: @n8te thanks. I am quite sure I have done everything right. I must be hitting some bug ...