# No host only interface in VM

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to configure a "Host only" interface, but it is not working.

What works:

- I am able to create a host only interface `vboxnet0`
- I am able to enable one interface in my VM configuration to use this host only interface
- The VM starts

What does not work:

- No interface is active on the VM connected to the host only driver.

I am running:

- VirtualBox Version 6.0.4 r128413 (Qt5.9.5)
- Host is Ubuntu 18.04.01

Why is the interface not active in the VM?

[image]

[image]

The interfaces in the VM (most are docker related):

```
user@butler ~ » ifconfig
br-40e6fe014032: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.20.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:f3ff:fe74:c41b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:f3:74:c4:1b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2  bytes 176 (176.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-85692f1ed6a2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:85ff:fee0:1cf1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:85:e0:1c:f1  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2  bytes 176 (176.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-bc449674774d: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        ether 02:42:cb:0f:b4:f3  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:eb:d2:6a:cc  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feb8:d2fd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:b8:d2:fd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1158  bytes 78668 (78.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1059  bytes 390704 (390.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 88  bytes 6620 (6.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 88  bytes 6620 (6.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: What machine is the `ifconfig` from? The host or guest? If it's the guest, how is docker involved?

Comment: @Seth It's in the guest. The VM has docker running too. I want to run services in containers in the VM